# How to efficiently and quickly broadcast across multiple dataframe columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two sets of dataframes. One of them is a reference that updates the other.

The reference dataframe is melted with pd.melt and is also a filtered product from another process I have. One of the columns of this melted dataframe is a reference id to the other dataframe. I am trying to broadcast an update across various columns and rows across on the second dataframe based on this ref id. Let me explain :

melted data or dataframe 1:

| other cols | RefID | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bla | 1 | ColumnA | cat |
| bla | 1 | ColumnB | mouse |
| bla | 2 | ColumnB | dog |
| bla | 3 | ColumnB | dog |
| bla | 3 | ColumnC | lion |
| bla | 4 | ColumnA | cat |

In the 2nd dataframe I would like to structure it based on the first melted df like so:

| other cols | RefID | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bla | 1 | cat | mouse |  |
| bla | 2 |  | dog |  |
| bla | 3 |  | dog | lion |
| bla | 4 | cat |  |  |
| bla | 5 |  |  |  |
| bla | 6 |  |  |  |

As you can see, based on the ref id and column name it gets  filled in.

Now, why not just use pivot the melted frame back to normal size and then do a join? Well, I could but I think there would be more overhead as the second dataframe has different row lengths + performance is a factor. I was thinking of using broadcasting but I couldn't implement it without looping. I don't want to loop as it is a bit time consuming. This is what I have right now :

```
refids = melted_df['RefID'].unique()
i = 0
while i<len(refids):
 q = melted_df.query("RefID=="+str(i))
 qcols = q['variable']
 second_df.iloc[refids[i], list(qcols)] = list(q[value])
 i+=1
```

Now this works fine but I think it is too slow. Imagine we have a few million rows to go through, this won't cut it. I tried without the loop by simply dumping whole of refid and whole of value but it gave incorrect results.

Anyone have any idea for optimization?

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
cols = ['other cols', 'RefID']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['bla'], range(1, len(df) + 1)], names=cols)

out = (df.pivot(index=cols, columns='variable', values='value')
       .reindex(idx).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

out:

```
  other cols  RefID ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
0        bla      1     cat   mouse     NaN
1        bla      2     NaN     dog     NaN
2        bla      3     NaN     dog    lion
3        bla      4     cat     NaN     NaN
4        bla      5     NaN     NaN     NaN
5        bla      6     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

if you don want make unnecessary rows of bottom, use following code:

```
out2 = (df.pivot(index=cols, columns='variable', values='value')
        .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)    
)
```

out2:

```
  other cols  RefID ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
0        bla      1     cat   mouse     NaN
1        bla      2     NaN     dog     NaN
2        bla      3     NaN     dog    lion
3        bla      4     cat     NaN     NaN
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'other cols': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla'], 'RefID': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4], 'variable': ['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC', 'ColumnA'], 'value': ['cat', 'mouse', 'dog', 'dog', 'lion', 'cat']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df:

```
  other cols  RefID variable  value
0        bla      1  ColumnA    cat
1        bla      1  ColumnB  mouse
2        bla      2  ColumnB    dog
3        bla      3  ColumnB    dog
4        bla      3  ColumnC   lion
5        bla      4  ColumnA    cat
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I think I am not explaining the problem correctly, although your solution did give me some more ideas. I have a lot to learn still. I am going to close this topic for now.